# record sound Synchronaouslly from 3 separate Microphone

Tags: matlab, audio, record

I try to record sound from 3 separate USB-Microphones. Using (Matlab 2008)
I use this Command:

%%           Definr audio Channel
      r1 = audiorecorder(44100, 16,1,1);
      r2 = audiorecorder(44100, 16,1,2);
      r3 = audiorecorder(44100, 16,1,3);

%%           Start record

```
   record(r1);     % speak into microphone...    
   record(r2);
   record(r3);
```

%%           Stop record

```
   stop(r1);
   stop(r2);
   stop(r3);
```

I want to compare between recorder files from 3 microphone, but Microphons dont start and stop record in same time. and alwayes there are about (1500 to 3000 sample) deferance between recorder files.
so the problem:
I want to start record (in 3 microphone) in same time. and Stop all in same time.
are there any command to start record in same time (or constant time, not same time exactly).

I hope I could exolain what i need
and hope find a help...................................Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using three separate `audiorecorder` objects, just use one and call its constructor with 3 in the third argument (nChannels - see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html ). This will instruct it to record three channels simultaneously. That is,

```
r = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 3, 1);
```